# how to JSON.parse data from server before getValue function runs?

Tags: jquery, easyautocomplete

I have the following setting for my easyautocompelete input box:

```
var optionsCCGSavingsAutocomplete = {
        url : "/api/sitecore/SirduplaCoUkCalculator/AutoCompleteCCGSavings",                
        getValue: function(element) {
            // return element.Text;
             console.log(element);
        },
        maxNumberOfElements: 20,
        match: {
            enabled: true
        },
        highlightPhrase: false,
        theme: "square",
        ajaxSettings: {
            method : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",     
            dataType : 'text',
            data : JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#CCGModel_Text').val()}),
            success: function(data) {
                return JSON.parse(data);
            }         
        },
        requestDelay: 400        
    };
```

I initialize it like so:

```
$("#CalculatorCCG #CCGModel_Text").easyAutocomplete(optionsCCGSavingsAutocomplete);
```

The problem is the data i get from the server i need to JSON.parse() the data before it can be used by [easyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-json), how do i JSON.parse the data before the `getValue()` function runs  ?

Comment: try to do a global "var" and populate it on your "success"

Comment: cant the server just return valid json?

Comment: @Alex thanks really not under my control , thats why i need a workaround

Comment: @gianquiroz will try that TY

Comment: @gianquiroz , the resposnse is actually an array